# C++ compiler option to allow the use of incomplete type in classes that make use of each other?

Tags: c++, function-declaration, incomplete-type, function-definition

Is there a compiler option that will allow the following code to compile, without moving the function definition to the bottom?

```
class first{
    int a;

    void func(second b){}

};

class second{
    int a;

    void func(first b){}
};
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not when you pass it by value. If you passed it by pointer or by reference you could.